# Are rem units only useful for font-size?

Tags: css, font-size

I'm using rems for all kind of elements such as:

```
html: 62.5%;

.element {
   font-size: 1.6rem;
   margin: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
   padding: 1rem;
   min-height: 3rem;
   height: 100%;
}
```

I've read some [articles](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) regarding the advantages of using REM and not PX. I'm currently using REM overall but I've began to think about if its only useful for font-size or not.

So, is REM useful in another elements or using them in all the elements is a bit overdone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A huge argument in favor of using rem or em units for your entire layout is that your entire layout will then scale with the text. This was important for accessibility with older browsers, which offered an option to increase the font size rather than the "zoom" feature that most browsers offer now. In order to make webpages more easily readable, persons with low visibility often increased the font size -- and in websites which use rem or em units for all elements on the page, the entire page would scale. This argument is *less* relevant now, but still important for legacy browser support (IE6 is still used in many schools and offices!).

Comment: @Wooddrow Barlow Therefore in modern browsers (IE9+) it seems that the font-size in REM is important but not relevant for other elements? So if you want to cover IE9+ its not necessary to use REM throughout your whole project? Also... older browser (IE8-) do not support REM units...

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero In IE8-, you'd probably use ems. I haven't heard a solid argument in favor of rems or ems besides the scaling argument, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: When you make the font size bigger with your keyboard is it the same as scaling the website? I'm not sure if I'm not understanding the whole advantage of the REM's. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero It depends on your browser. Most browsers now offer full zoom scaling rather than adjusting font-size. Full zoom scaling is effectively the same as pinch-zooming on a mobile browser -- the whole page is scaled as if it were a single element.

Comment: luckily in 2023, we have no __older__ browsers anymore (only _none_ compliant ones like iOS Safari) What is confusing me is to use `rem` instead of `em` like in bootrstraps `_reboot.scss`. Typographical this makes no sense as one expects for instance consecutive <p> to be one line (`1em`) apart. In a classed p `em` could very well differ from `rem`.