# Same height and width on page resize

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap with Angular 9 and a rounded profile picture. If I put `width: 19rem` and `height: 19rem` the picture keeps rounded but when I have a smaller resolution it overflows onto the next column.

Is there any way to keep width 100% and the height dynamically changes so it has the same aspect ratio (rounded)?

Thank you so much!

```
.mainImage {
  height: 19rem;
  width: 19rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px #35c68f solid;
}
```

Comment: can u put both html and css code?

Comment: why `rem` and why not `%`? Read [are-rem-units-only-useful-for-font-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361748/are-rem-units-only-useful-for-font-size) and [CSS Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361748/are-rem-units-only-useful-for-font-size)

Comment: check out https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ for other use cases

Comment: @kokorosama did my answer below helped?

Answer (score 1):

Use view port:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/vm37b5gu/39/) to check responsiveness.

```css
.mainImage {
  height: 15vw;
  width: 15vw;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px #35c68f solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="mainImage" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
</div>
```

on `65vm` size:

```css
.mainImage {
  height: 65vw;
  width: 65vw;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px #35c68f solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="mainImage" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand is: if you want all image to fit a rounded circle, you can include this to image

```
img = { object-fit: cover; }
```